# Getting an objects variable with events

Tags: javascript, object

```
function test() {
    this.str = "hello";

    this.sayHello = function() {
        document.write(this.str);
    }

    this.init = function() {
        document.onkeydown = this.sayHello;
    }
}

var testing = new test();
testing.init();
```

The above code should output "hello" on an onkeydown event.
But I get "undefined". How can I get this to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `this.sayHello`. When you assign the reference to the `sayHello` function on keydown, the reference to the context (object) is lost. When a key is pressed, `this` refers to the `Document` object as the callback is invoked as:

```
document.onkeydown(); // or for simplicity imagine - document.sayHello();
```

If you assigned the `str` variable on the `document` object, you would see the value logged,

```
document.str = "hello";
```

However, that is not what you'd want. You need to wrap the keydown event handler inside another function to preserve the context to that object. Two ways to go about this. You could either wrap the event handler inside another function, and preserve the reference to this.

```
this.init = function() {
    var me = this;
    document.onkeydown = function() {
        me.sayHello();
    };
}
```

Or, if you're using modern browsers, this has already been incorporated into ECMAScript 5 using the `bind` function.

```
this.init = function() {
    var me = this;
    document.onkeydown = this.sayHello.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Exactly, what I've been looking for. Thank you very much!